# iOS Developer Account - Multiple apps for Multiple clients

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise, apple-developer-account

I am currently working in a company that make mobile applications for multiple client, our clients varies from companies to government organizations, It's possible to create one apple developer account to publish all the apps on the app store ?

Comment: Yes, make sure their bundle Id is different and not to violate any apple  guidlines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is suggestion based question and never is asked again by other user.

Comment: @dahiya_boy right.

Comment: sorry if I posted the wrong question but I made my research for days and never found an answer for this question, because we have faced a problem apple rejected our app because it's the name of the app related to a government organization that our company is working for, we created a new organization account which held the name of the organization and apple accept our app, so if for every client we need to create an apple account it's gonna be hard to manage multiple accounts

Comment: so If there is another platform to post that kind of question, please let me know and I will remove the question by myself

Comment: @AntoineElMurr My organisation apple account have many MNCs projects and with their name. We never faced such issue. Probably it should be any other issue but you can confirm with Apple support. I don't think apple have any issue with uploading projects in same developer account.

Comment: @AntoineElMurr StackOverflow is basically for the coding related issues. If you wanted some discussion then you can post on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ . But I'm  sure about how that community will respond on this question.

Comment: The correct process is for each of your clients to have their own developer membership in their own organisation name. They should then make you a member of that program so that you can submit apps to the App Store. You should not publish apps for other organisations under your own account; it is highly likely that the apps will be rejected if you do.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 I think you are totally right, because we have recently faced a rejection when we uploaded an app of another organization, and the solution was for the other organization to create there own developer membership.